Get rid of "ValueError: The TextBackend supports only one graph per Plot"
I want to plot two curves simultaneously using sympy library.
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot
x = symbols('x')
plot(x,x**2)

I'm getting the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    plot(x**2, x)
  File "C:\Users\MANJOY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\plot.py", line 1873, in plot
    plots.show()
  File "C:\Users\MANJOY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\plot.py", line 251, in show
    self._backend.show()
  File "C:\Users\MANJOY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\plot.py", line 1575, in show
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The TextBackend supports only one graph per Plot. 

How to get rid of this? I need sympy only.
I tried:
sympy.plot(x,x**2, show=True)

I thought if I used show=True, it would work. But unfortunately this does not work.
I am using Python IDLE 3.11.2.

you need to install matplotlib.

Also note that if you just want to plot a function with x on the x-axis and x**2 on the y-axis with sympy you should call plot(x**2).

@JohanC I am plotting two curves y=x^2 and y=x

Generally, a question will be more effective and useful to others if you start from a position of what you want to do, then add what is not working for you.  For example, the title here might be "How do I plot two curves using the sympy library".

You can draw two curves with sympy.plot(x,x**2) if you have matplotlib installed. Without access to matplotlib, the plot is shown in text format, which only allied to draw one curve.  Please explain more carefully what you are trying to do, and the parts that do work.

@JohanC I didn't have matplotlib. So I installed it and it seems all ok now

@JohanC I'm sorry that I couldn't convey a clear message to you. But a) I mentioned that I wanted simultaneous plotting of two curves. b) If I had any idea about installing matplotlib, I would do so. I was unaware of the fact that maltplotlib is still required even if I'm working with sympy. I'm just a beginner in Python and new to this community too. However, great to be enlightened by your wisdom and effort
